# Programmatically adding two text fields to a tableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

I would like to programmatically add two text fields to an tableViewCell sub-class (more later) but having difficultly accessing the text-field from the view controller.

My table view sub class is:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;
        textField.textAlignment = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters;
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        [self.contentView addSubview:textField];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect rect2 = CGRectMake(100.0, 10.0, 200, 30.0);
    textField.text = @"testing";
    [textField setFrame:rect2];

}
```

Within my view controller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    XTSessionCell_iPad *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier    forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[XTSessionCell_iPad alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

   // Configure the cell...
   // ????
   // cell.textField.text = @"enter";

   return cell;
}
```

Any help very much appricatated.

Thanks

Comment: You should define the textFields as properties (`@property`) of the `XTSessionCell_iPad`. This should be done in header `@interface` (.h file, not .m file)

Comment: So you wanna add them on to a tableview cell? It seems you're adding them to the contentView here. Is that your table?

Comment: @rokjarc Make them read-only properties.

Comment: @interface XTSessionCell_iPad : UITableViewCell
{
    UITextField *textField;
}`
@property (readwrite) UITextField *textField;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned in the comments, make the `textView` a readonly property in your XTSessionCell_iPad.h file. At a minimum your XTSessionCell_iPad.h file would look like:

```
@interface XTSessionCell_iPad : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, readonly) UITextField *textField;

@end
```

And your XTSessionCell_iPad.m file would have a class extension to allow writing to that property:

```
@interface XTSessionCell_iPad()

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) UITextField *textField;

@end
```